# Filter based on collection or sub-attribute

Tags: laravel

My user model has a 'prevregistration' attribute

```
 public function prevregistration()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Prevregistration::class, 'prevregistration_userid');
}
```

My prevregistraton model has a 'prev' attribute

```
  public function prev()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Prev::class,'prev_id', 'prevregistration_previd');
}
```

In my controller I show prevregistrations for the current user:

```
mynextprevs = Auth::user()->prevregistration ;
```

Now I want to only show prevregistrations from which the connected prev its prev_date in the future, like this:

```
$mynextprevs = Auth::user()->prevregistration::whereDate('prev_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

But then I get:

> BadMethodCallException
> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereDate does not exist.

I also tried like this:

```
$mynextprevs = Auth::user()->prevregistration->prev::whereDate('prev_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

But then I get:

> Property [prev] does not exist on this collection instance.

Should I/how can I filter the collection? I'm curious why Auth::user()->prevregistration->prev is not working, since that are attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the condition `whereHas` on your prevregistration

```php
$mynextprevs = Auth::user()->prevregistration()->whereHas('prev',function($prev) {
    $prev->whereDate('prev_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
})->get();
```

Notice we used the relation as a method `prevregistration()` to access it as a query builder and not as a collection hence the need for the `->get()` at the end.